# At what temperatures would the gearing for geared turbofans be rendered unnecessary?

Tags: turbofan, efficiency, geared-turbofan

If geared turbofans were fitted with material science technologies or other engineering innovations that would allow them to operate at higher temperatures exceeding their current most optimum operating efficiency, at what point or temperatures would gearing be rendered unnecessary?

Comment: Temperature increases the efficiency of the turbine. Gearing increases the efficiency of the fan. Both are important, increasing one doesn't mean you can ignore the other.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of the question is wrong.  Gearing has nothing to do with temperature limitation, rather speed limitation.  Turbines are most efficient when the run fast, fans are most efficient when they run slow.  In a normal engine, the fan and LPT are forced to run at the same speed.  So there is always a tradeoff.  Usually the LPT is forced to run much slower than optimal. For example, compare the PW1100G to the LEAP-1A.  The LEAP has a 7 stage LPT, but the PW1100G has only a 3 stage LPT.  In order words, because it is able to run faster, each stage of the PW1100G is about 2x more efficient than a LEAP LPT stage.  Therefore, it only needs half as many stages to do the same amount of work.  This is only a speed thing, nothing to do with temperatures.